# Exploring Python Exercise

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning Python from the book *Exploring Python* by Timothy Budd. One of the exercises from this chapter is this:

15. The function `randint` from the random module can be used to produce random numbers. A call on `random.randint(1, 6)`, for example, will produce the values 1 to 6 with equal probability. Write a program that loops 1000 times. On each iteration it makes two calls on `randint` to simulate rolling a pair of dice. Compute the sum of the two dice, and record the number of times each value appears. Afterthe loop, print the array of sums. You can initialize the array using the idiom shown earlier in this chapter:

`times = [0] * 12 # make an array of 12 elements, initially zero`

I am able to print the sum in the array, but I have not understood the concept of recording the number of times each value appears. Also, what purpose would `times = [0]` serve? Here is my code for printing the sum:

```
 #############################################
#   Program to print the sum of dice rolls  #
#############################################

from random import randint
import sys


times = [0] * 12

summation = []

def diceroll():

    print "This program will print the"
    print "sum of numbers, which appears"
    print "after each time the dice is rolled."
    print "The program will be called 1000 times"



    for i in range(1,1000):

        num1 = randint(1,6)
        num2 = randint(1,6)

        sum = num1 + num2
        summation.append(sum)
        #times[i] = [i] * 12
    print summation
    #print times


diceroll()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count number of occurrences:

```
times = [0]*13
for _ in range(1000):
    sum_ = randint(1, 6) + randint(1, 6)
    times[sum_] += 1

print(times[2:])
```

Possible values of sum_ are 2...12 including. Possible `times` indexes are 0...12 including.

`times[i]` corresponds to a number of occurrences of `sum_ == i` among 1000 tries.

Note: `times[0]` and `times[1]` are always zero because `sum_ > 1`

`[x]*3` produces `[x, x, x]` It is a nicer version of:

```
L = []
L.append(x)
L.append(x)
L.append(x)
```

Additional comments about your code:

- `print something` is an error on Python 3
- `for i range(1, 1000)` is wrong. It produces i from 1 to 999 including (999 iterations instead of 1000 as required). `range` doesn't include upper limit as it customery for intervals in programming.

Comment: times[sum_-1] += 1, is that -1 with the purpose of reversing the order?

Comment: Sebastian: Yes, range has to be from 0 to 1001, to iterate 1000 times. Also, for the first sum, times = 0, but when first sum appears, then time or occurence is not zero, i guess this is an error.

Comment: @vamosrafa: I've simplified the code a bit. There is no error as far as I can see. I've initially considered the `times = [0]*12` to be a requirement for the exercise.

Comment: Sebastian: i have understood the problem now. Suppose the sum is 4, and 4 occurs 24 times, so in times array, the number of occurerces of sum is printed. And the lenght will be 12, because dice is from 1 to 6, so two dice = 12. Also, the sum of the element of array would be 1000. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

`times[0] * 12` initiates a list of 12 elements with value 0.  What you want to do next is

```
times[s] += 1 #adds 1 to the number of times s occurs
```

This is similar to using a dict to encode a value, but its simpler.

`times = [0]` initializes a list called times of length 1 and value 0.  The idiom `times = [0] * 12` means times is a list of 12 zeroes.

If you want to be able to use this without keyerror when `num1==num2==6`, you need to do `times = [0]*13` because python is a 0 indexed system.

Sidenote: Don't use `sum` as a variable name because it is a builtin function (predefined) and you don't want to override it. Use `times[sum([num1,num2])] += 1` or `times[num1+num2]` instead.

Comment: so summation[sum(num1 + num2)] +=1 would give me the sum of rolls of dice.

Comment: `num1 + num2` is already a sum, so there's no need to call `sum` on it. It's a `TypeError` anyway, as `sum` expects a list. But yes, putting `times[sum] += 1` in your loop instead of `summation.append(sum)` would give you the sum of dice rolls.

Comment: No, it will update the list summation to record the right numbers.  summation[i] will give you the number of sums adding up to i (if i is < 12).

Comment: Since python lists are 0-indexed, you will actually need to initiate times as a list of 13 if you want to be able to call times[12]

Comment: oh yes, my mistake, I wanted to write Sum, instead wrote sum. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: So, i should not use append function then?

Comment: @vamosrafa That's right, the `append` function and the `summation` list is not needed. Also, you should not use capitalized variable names like `Sum` for normal objects like for example numbers or lists, they are normally [reserved for classes](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions).

Comment: There are certain unenforced but highly encouraged conventions for naming, such as lowercase for variables, capital for classes, etc.  There should be another stackoverflow thing on it.

Comment: when i used times[num1 + num2], the program throws an error message, list index out of range. Is is because i am looping for 1000 times, but num1 and num2 have a range between 1 to 6. I think it is because of this.

Comment: Edited my answer.  It's because num1 + num2 == 12 if num1==num2==6, which causes times[12], which exists if the length of times is greater than or equal to 13.